# Como buscar array no postgres através do sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Minha base de dados possui uma coluna do tipo `ARRAY(sa.BIGINT)`. Minha intenção é utilizar o comando `filter_by`do sqlalchemy para buscar um elemento que tenha o campo list_secao_id igual a [58,45,12], por exemplo:

```
instance = session.query(model).filter_by(**{'list_secao_id': [58,45,12]}).first()
```

Contudo, estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: bigint[] = integer[]

LINE 3: ...corte.recorte_ordem = 1 AND recorte.list_secao_id = ARRAY[58...

HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Tentei realizar o cast, porém, não tive sucesso:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import ARRAY

instance = session.query(model).filter_by(**{'list_secao_id': ARRAY([58,45,12])}).first()
```

Erro:

```
Object has no attribute self_group
```

Como posso alterar minha query afim de obter sucesso na busca por lista?

Comment: Qual DBAPI você está usando? psycopg2?

Comment: Isso, psycopg2 é a dbapi